# How can I make sure Linux only uses secure connections?

Tags: tls, linux, internet

Suppose I need to connect to the internet but I cannot (or I don't want to) trust anything outside of my laptop. Therefore I will need to make sure all connections are secure, so I guess this means they should be encrypted and the destination should be able to be trusted.

To browse the web, I can use Firefox with the plugin "HTTPS Everywhere" set to "block every unencrypted request", and if I'm not mistaken I guess that should be enough for surfing the internet. However, browsing the web is only part of the story. There could be some processes or applications that don't make secure connections, including "default" or "core" applications like the system updater itself, or some applications maybe be misconfigured. So what should I do to make sure Linux only uses secure connections that can be trusted, even at the cost of having to avoid or block any insecure connections?

Comment: Which threat are you protecting against? TLS will only ever help against MiTM attacks and eavesdropping.

Comment: @vidarlo, basically not trusting anything between my laptop and the destination, especially not trusting the local network (and not trusting VPNs either). Some exceptions could be made for example for Google's DNS, I can trust their services, but not everything that's between me and them (unless the connection is secure). So you see why the question is about "secure connections".

Comment: Set up a VPN tunnell to the target. Set up firewall rules that drop traffic to all other destinations.

Comment: Run your own VPN server if you don't trust 3rd party VPN. There are plenty of non-commercial VPN software you can use.

Comment: @BernardWei I don't think a VPN will be the same as a sytem-wide "HTTPS Everywhere". That what I'd be interested in.

Comment: Voting to close as "Too Broad". A system-wide "HTTPS Everywhere" does not exist; that would require modifying every software on the system one-by-one to make sure it's using TLS.

Answer (score 1):

> To browse the web, I can use Firefox with the plugin "HTTPS Everywhere" set to "block every unencrypted request", and if I'm not mistaken I guess that should be enough for surfing the internet.

-

> basically not trusting anything between my laptop and the destination, especially not trusting the local network (and not trusting VPNs either). Some exceptions could be made for example for Google's DNS, I can trust their services, but not everything that's between me and them (unless the connection is secure). So you see why the question is about "secure connections"

This doesn't make any sense at all. Why would you trust a TLS encrypted connection to random sites, but not trust a VPN solution?

TLS will *not* protect you against malware. It will protect you against eavesdropping and MiTM-attacks.

Ubuntu, for instance, uses signatures and timestamping to secure updates against tampering, even though it's transmitted over plain http. At worst, an attacker can force you to not get updates; he can't really give you malware via the update mechanism.

If you have a remote device you have to access securely, set up a VPN to that service, terminating as close to the service as possible. Drop all other other outgoing traffic from your laptop.

Oh, and I'm *very* curious about your chain of thoughts leading to your conclusions about security...

Comment: And blocking package updates (because they're not secured at connection level) will make you less secure pretty quickly.

Comment: A VPN can read all the traffic, a random site only sees whatever I send to it. I never mentioned malware in general, the point is in fact only about eavesdropping and MITM, so any possible malware has to be injected in the connection (MITM). As I said, I am assuming I can trust my laptop and the destination, but not what's in between, so the conclusion is pretty obvious: if HTTPS is a must for this scenario in a browser, how can the equivalent be achieved system-wide? Could be some steps to take, stuff to check, rules in iptables, etc, I don't know.

Comment: Or the malware may be served up in ads... over https.